# android ormlite issue with database field foreign its becaume null when i retrieve them from database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

Hi everybody and sorry for my english.

I have a big problem that I can't understand. I create a table with `ORMLITE` that contains a foreign field in the same table. I insert it but when I retrieve it, it always null.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Menu")
public class MenuDo {

    private static final String MENU_PARENT = "menu_parent";
    /**id unique dans la base de donnée*/
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true,unique=true)
    private Long id;
    /**le gabarit du sous menu qui sera renvoyé par le WS*/
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull=true,columnName="gabarit")
    private String gabarit;
    /**Le label du menu qui sera renvoyé par le WS*/
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull=true,columnName="label")
    private String label;
    /**url de la redirection généralement redirection vers la liste des articles d'une rubrique*/
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull=true,columnName="url")
    private String url;
    /**Le nom de la rubrique du l'item du menu*/
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull=true,columnName="rubrique_id")
    private String rubriqueId;
    /**les sous menu contenu dans le menu*/
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = MenuDo.MENU_PARENT)
    private MenuDo menuParent;
}
```

i insert like this

```
public void insert(final List<MenuDo> menuDo) throws SQLException {


     configurationRepository = new ConfigurationRepositoryImpl(context);
        TransactionManager.callInTransaction(
                configurationRepository.getConnectionSource(),
                new Callable<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object call() throws Exception {
                        deleteAll();
                        for(MenuDo menu:menuDo)
                        {
                            insert(menu);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });

}
```

methode to insert in database  :

```
@Override
public void insert(C entity) {
    if(entity!=null){
        if(abstractRunTimeExceptionDao.create(entity)==0){
            throw new TechnicalException(INSERT_ERROR_MESSAGE + entity.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

there is no error in the insertion and  i already verify menu have parent menu not null before insertion

but `menuParent` is always null when I retrieve elements from database.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Please provide some example of your current usage of this class. Did you remember to add the inner "MenuDo menuParent" to the instance MenuDo and then update / create it ?

Comment: hi, i just update my message

Comment: Why are you using "columnName = MenuDo.MENU_PARENT" ? This may be loopy. Please try with only @DatabaseField(foreign = true), and beware that you should have the "MenuDo menuParent" reference not null inside the object when you persist it and already referencing some object that is already persisted on the database.

Comment: MenuDo.MENU_PARENT = "menu_parent" i do this because i can use the name of this column to do request like this ... where MenuDo.MENU_PARENT is not null for example. 

i set menuParent before i insert any menu in database

Comment: you're right i try something like that        for(int i=0;i<menuDo.size();i++)
       {
        MenuDo menu = menuDo.get(i);
        if(i>0)
         menu.setMenuParent(menuDo.get(i-1));
        insert(menu);
       }

and it's work so the problem was persist